# Get Dependent Picklist from salesforce without apex and show it in page using php code

Tags: apex, picklist

I am able to get the "Type" fields Dependent field lists. But I can't find the child list for the particular parent drop-down.

Here is my code.

```
$finalApplicableOptions[$j][1] = array();
for($i=0;$i < count($result->fields); $i++){

        if($result->fields[$i]->name == "Type__c"){
            $sub = count($result->fields[$i]->picklistValues);
            for($j=0;$j<count($result->fields[$i]->picklistValues); $j++){
                $byteArr = $result->fields[$i]->picklistValues[$j]->validFor;

                $maparray = array();
                $map = "";
                foreach(str_split($byteArr) as $c)
                    $maparray [] = sprintf("%08b", ord($c));
                $map = implode("", $maparray );
                for ($k = 0; $k < strlen($map); $k++){
                    if($map{$k} == "1"){
                        $finalApplicableOptions[$j][1][] =  $result->fields[$i]->picklistValues[$j]->label;
                    }

                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Any one help me. Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible to show the dependent picklist using PHP + JS. I have done this without Salesforce VF page.

Referred the above link( https://iwritecrappycode.wordpress.com/2012/02/23/dependent-picklists-in-salesforce-without-metadata-api-or-visualforce/ ).

**I used the below steps:**

## 1. Get the salesforce "Tasks" objects using "describeSObject" API via PHP.

## 2. Set PHP describe object result to "describeResults" in onready function. Removed the Included JS file and apex code.

## 3. I change the below code

From:
    var base64 = new sforce.Base64Binary("");
    var decoded = base64.decode(validFor);

To:
    var decoded = atob(validFor);

## 4. Run the code. It works Good!!!

I hope it will help anyone.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This should help you - Just provide appropriate field names!
https://iwritecrappycode.wordpress.com/2012/02/23/dependent-picklists-in-salesforce-without-metadata-api-or-visualforce/

Comment: Thanks For your help d_k. I tried this, got an error sforce.connection.sessionId: sf is undefined error occured. I included the three js files. Could you please help to fix this issue. Is there any way to done using PHP Code.

Comment: The JS will remain the same the syntax might differ a bit,  Also are you using the latest files?

Comment: Yes I used the latest files. **ajax/30.0/connection.js**

Comment: Can you share the screenshot of the code and error as well?

Comment: I cant upload my Screenshots.

Code:

Comment: Code:
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.js" />
<script src="connection.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="apex.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="pickList.js"></script>
<script>
//get a session id token to use the js libs
sforce.connection.sessionId = "{}";
//describe the object we are dealing with. You'll need to change this to whatever object you are working with. Use the API name of the object.'
var describeResults = sforce.connection.describeSObject('Type');

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: sforce is not defined(anonymous function) @ apex.js:2
Uncaught ReferenceError: sforce is not defined(anonymous function) @test.php:11

Comment: It looks like this sforce.connection.sessionId = "{}"; should be like this - sforce.connection.sessionId = "{!$Api.Session_ID}";

Comment: Same error occurred while i tried with your code.

Comment: Where are you trying this? a VF page?

Comment: I am not use the VF page. created a test page in my apache. Trying to get **Type** dependency fields and show it in my page. I tried using PHP.  The only problem is relate with dependency field using bitmap.

Comment: Can you first try it in VF page? in your org?

Comment: I tried with my developer account ( VF page ). It works fine. But i need to do in PHP.

Comment: I'm not sure about PHP